# How can one find out what TLS ciphers a specific version of .NET supports?

Tags: .net, tls1.2

So I have an app that is deployed on 2 environments, my own, and a client's environment. On my environment, it works as expected, while the client has issues. During my investigations, I found (I consider this to be the problem) that even if the same ciphers are specified in tomcat's server.xml, the client has in his logs entries like `Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` for ciphers that on my local machine seem to be used to make the app work.

we are both using windows server 2012 r2...which unfortuanetly does not support in its powerShell these commands that can be useful in such times: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=win10-ps

I don't know what version of .NET my client uses, but i will find out, and most likely it will be different..hence I want to make sure that this is the cause of the issue, by finding the list supported by a specific .NET version. Microsoft has pages where it mentions the ciphers based on OS version (like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1803) but not based on .NET...or at least I couldn't find them...

Thx